# Vertical Carousel Layout android

Tags: android, carousel

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FeatureCoverFlow coverFlow;
    private CoverFlowAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Game> games;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        coverFlow = (FeatureCoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);

        settingDummyData();
        adapter = new CoverFlowAdapter(this, games);
        coverFlow.setAdapter(adapter);
        coverFlow.setOnScrollPositionListener(onScrollListener());
    }

    private FeatureCoverFlow.OnScrollPositionListener onScrollListener() {
        return new FeatureCoverFlow.OnScrollPositionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolledToPosition(int position) {
                Log.v("MainActiivty", "position: " + position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolling() {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "scrolling");
            }
        };
    }

    private void settingDummyData() {
        games = new ArrayList<>();
        games.add(new Game(R.mipmap.assassins_creed, "Assassin Creed 3"));
        games.add(new Game(R.mipmap.avatar_3d, "Avatar 3D"));
        games.add(new Game(R.mipmap.call_of_duty_black_ops_3, "Call Of Duty Black Ops 3"));
        games.add(new Game(R.mipmap.dota_2, "DotA 2"));
        games.add(new Game(R.mipmap.halo_5, "Halo 5"));
        games.add(new Game(R.mipmap.left_4_dead_2, "Left 4 Dead 2"));
        games.add(new Game(R.mipmap.starcraft, "StarCraft"));
        games.add(new Game(R.mipmap.the_witcher_3, "The Witcher 3"));
        games.add(new Game(R.mipmap.tomb_raider, "Tom raider 3"));
        games.add(new Game(R.mipmap.need_for_speed_most_wanted, "Need for Speed Most Wanted"));
    }
}
```

//this is my activity

```
public class CoverFlowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Game> data;
    private AppCompatActivity activity;

    public CoverFlowAdapter(AppCompatActivity context, ArrayList<Game> objects) {
        this.activity = context;
        this.data = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Game getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_flow_view, null, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.gameImage.setImageResource(data.get(position).getImageSource());
        viewHolder.gameName.setText(data.get(position).getName());

        convertView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener(final int position) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_game_info);
                dialog.setCancelable(true); // dimiss when touching outside
                dialog.setTitle("Game Details");

                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
                text.setText(getItem(position).getName());
                ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setImageResource(getItem(position).getImageSource());

                dialog.show();
            }
        };
    }


    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView gameName;
        private ImageView gameImage;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            gameImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            gameName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }
}
```

//This is my adapter.Now everythings runs fine but I want to make this coverflow vertically.there is no option of setting orientation in xml..I have tried http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel.. But I don't want this type of carousel layout I need simple vertical carousel layout.

Comment: Use a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager` with vertical Orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can achieve this using viewpager2. We can specify Orientation like recyclerview 'viewPager.orientation = ORIENTATION_VERTICAL'.

Go through this

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2

https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-view-pager-2-86dbce06ff71

Answer (score 0):

There are many workarounds to implement it. But I prefer to use a viewPager2 it supports vertical orientation.

or you can use a library to implement it like [this library](https://github.com/IslamKhSh/CardSlider)